# Get purchase details based on user

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

It is possible to get email-based in-app subscription purchase details.

For my checking, I got purchase details based on the Play Store mail ID.

User A subscribed the plan 1 (Play Store account example xyz).

- Plan 1 expired. At the time "user A logout" and "user B logged" into the same mobile
- Now resubscribed by the user on the Play Store (After expired time).
- Now "user B" (Mail id: 123@gmail.com) enters the app new token will be it but here user B not doing the subscription.

So I need mail ID-based purchase data.